# 2 criteria named range Excel

Tags: named-ranges

I wanted to make quarterly named ranges, but requires 2 criteria E.G Location and 1st qtr, location and 2nd qtr, ext...

in name manager its A1 location : Jan - Mar = Qtr1; A1 location (control) and Apr - Jun = Qtr2, A1 Location (control) and Jul - Sep = Qtr3

What would be the solution to get total quarterly data for each quarter. I tried filter but gives me the REF#
=SUM(FILTER(**QTR2_Bud_Rev_MTD**,Budget!B7:B29='Act Vs Bud Qtrly Sum'!B5))

bold is where the issue is

=SUM(FILTER(**QTR2_Bud_Rev_MTD**,Budget!B7:B29='Act Vs Bud Qtrly Sum'!B5))

Expecting to give me total 2nd qtr info for 1 location in the data set

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNRAt.png)

expecting [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mLhR.png)